React Test : How to test useRef and useImperativeHandle block of code
I am working on a React enterprise application, there are two components I am working on, with Parent-Child relationship. The child has a function which has to be called by the parent. I implemented this using forwardRef method and use of useImperativeHandle hook.
The code works fine but I am stuck at the testing part, how could I test this hook and also if the function validate() inside the hook has been called.
PS : I could not create the function in parent and pass it to child through props, so I have to follow this approach.
This is how the relationship looks like. I couldn't paste the actual code!!
function Parent() {
    const childRef = useRef(null);
    
    const handleClick = () => {
      childRef?.current?.validateInputs();
    }

    return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
       <Child ref={childRef} />
     </div> 
    )
}

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => {
      validateInputs() {
       //some code
      }
    })

    return <div>jsx</div> 
})

This is what I have written so far!! How could I test the validate() function call
it('#validate should call on button click', () => {
  const {getByText} = render(<Parent/>);
  const btn = getByText('Click');
  const fn = jest.spyOn(React, "useImperativeHandle")
  fireEvent.click(btn);
  waitFor(() => expect(fn).toHaveBeenCalled());
})


What does the validateInputs function do? Show the minimal, complete code

validateInputs() loop through a series of radio inputs if value of any of them is empty it then it returns false else true. I couldn’t paste the code because I work in VDI so we are not allowed to do that anyhow
